# Different dimensions for hdpi and xhdpi phones

Tags: java, android

There is the following problem: I'd like to use one size (20dip) for hdpi phones and an other size (30 dip) for xhdpi phones. Is it possible to store these sizes in files with dimensions or I must do it programmatically? Please, give me advice. Thanks.

Comment: Follow this http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#density-independence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better use **dimension** to define **size**..

```
res>values-hdpi>dimen.xml
```

**dimen.xml**

```
<dimen name="size">20dp</dimen>
```

And in the same way

```
res>values-xhdpi>dimen.xml
```

**dimen.xml**

```
<dimen name="size">30dp</dimen>
```

Like so on for other density.

Answer (score 1):

This is done by creating two folders : values-large and values-xlarge.
Add the appropriate dimension value within the file dimens.xml and place them in each of above folders.

for eg : 
**values-large/dimens.xml** :

```
<dimen name="view_size">20dip</dimen>
```

and in **values-xlarge/dimens.xml** :

```
<dimen name="view_size">35dip</dimen>
```